# Problem with table and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I get a problem with the following table:

```
\begin{table}[H]  
    \newcommand{\ctab}{\centering\arraybackslash}  
    \definecolor{F1}{RGB}{255,255,255}  
    \definecolor{F0}{RGB}{210,0,0}  
    \definecolor{F2}{RGB}{0,176,80}  
    \resizebox{0.85\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
            \hline   
            \rule{0pt}{30pt}  
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{a}}} &
            %\cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{a}} &  
            %\cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{}} &
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{b}} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{C}} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{$\mathbf{d}$} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{$\mathbf{e}$}    
            \\   
            \end{tabular}}  
    \caption{XY}  
    \label{tab:XY}  
\end{table}
```

Problems are with the multicolumn. If I change to:

```
%\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{a}}} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{a}} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{}} &
```

It does work...

Where is the Problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note, that your question does not show a minimal working example. For an explanation on MWE take a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050).

Comment: Also note, that I don't think that `\huge` is necessary to highlight the top row (it's coloured already). Also I personally dislike vertical lines in tables (and know several other people who share my opinion on that). You might take a look at the `booktabs` package for prettier horizontal rules (but they tend to break the vertical rules and `\rowcolor`/`\cellcolor`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by your `\rule` in conjunction with `\multicolumn` because it is in the same cell as the `\multicolumn`. If you want to keep it, place it in another cell or inside the `\multicolumn`. If you just want decent spacing you might insert a `\strut` just after `\huge`.

Using `\rule`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
            \hline   
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{a}}{\rule{0pt}{30pt}}} &
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{b}} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{C}} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{$\mathbf{d}$} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{$\mathbf{e}$}    
            \\
            \hline
            f&g&h&i&j&k\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
    \caption{XY}  
    \label{tab:XY}  
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

produces:
[image]

Using `\strut`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
            \hline   
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\huge\strut{\textbf{a}}} &
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{b}} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{\textbf{C}} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{$\mathbf{d}$} &  
            \cellcolor{gray!50}\huge{$\mathbf{e}$}    
            \\   
            \hline
            f&g&h&i&j&k\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
    \caption{XY}  
    \label{tab:XY}  
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

produces:
[image]

Comment: The`\extrarowheight` length is done for padding. Another solution is the `cellspace` package.

Comment: @Bernard didn't know that length. But I like the look of the `\strut`-solution, the spacing seems just right to me. You might add an answer showing the two solutions you suggest (and take my upvote :P)

Comment: I didn't say it was a bad spacing! I think it's not in the spirit of LaTeX to fiddle with individual cells, and in general formatting commands within the body of the document should be avoided. Of course this remark does not take into account particular situations.

Comment: @Bernard the fiddle with individual cells is just used because of the `\huge`. I don't think that the `\huge` in the head row is good practise but with a `\huge\strut` it gets correct spacing. Is `\extrarowheight` just applicable to the whole table (I haven't tested)?

Comment: Yes, it applies to all rows, but as  padding is very tight in the default settings of LaTeX, that's no problem. More interesting is `cellspace`, which defines *minimal* vertical spacings at the top and bottom of cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\extrarowheight` to add some padding at the top of *all* cells (it's hardly a luxury, considering the tightness of default row heights), or define a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns prefixed with the letter `S`.

I simplified the code using the `\rowcolor` command, and defining a `\myhead` command which comprises the font changes. I took the liberty to change the colour of the first row to a nicer shade of gray:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{ cellspace}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
\newcommand{\myhead}[1]{\huge\boldmath\bfseries#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{Sc|}}
            \hline
       \rowcolor{GhostWhite!80!Gainsboro} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\myhead{a}}&
            \myhead{b} &
            \myhead{C} &
            \myhead{$\mathbf{d}$} &
            \myhead{$\mathbf{e}$}
            \\
            \hline
            f&g&h&i&j&k\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
    \caption{XY}
    \label{tab:XYZ}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]